# Amplify Not Pulling Remote Lambda Changes

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

My project is a react JS AWS Amplify project. I have a couple lambda functions setup for my project's REST API.

I made a few changes on the AWS lambda console to fix small errors in the code. When try to use `amplify pull` to pull the code changes to the lambda function to my local it does not detect any changes and will not change my local function code.

My `<project-root>/amplify/#current-cloud-backend/...` is still not up to date with what I see on the AWS lambda console. I have also tried the command `amplify pull --restore`.

Comment: Does this start working if you wait e.g. 1h or no?

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2020 this was not supported behavior, [see issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5424) (closed due to inactivity):

> The changes to the Lambda function will not be reflected back, but you can export the function and copy the changes manually